# Two-point correlation function for metric perturbation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, effective-field-theory

Can anyone explain how to calculate this two-point correlation function for metric perturbation?

\begin{equation}
\langle h_{\mu\nu}(x) h_{\alpha\beta}(y)\rangle
\end{equation}

Comment: There are a lot of details here that matter for answering. Is this for quantum field theory or a stochastic background or something else? If it's quantum field theory do you want the time ordered correlation function? What prior experience do you have with similar calculations (e.g. can you compute the two point function for a scalar field?) What gauge are you working in? Anyway this calculation is done many places, an example is Section 2.3 of the 2011 review by Hinterbichler https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3735 (the result you want is Eq 2.54).

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your feedback. The gauge I am considering is harmonic, and the metric perturbation is assumed to be trace reversed. This is for quantum effective field theory and the correlation function is NOT time ordered. Yes, I have some prior experience with scalar fields. The reference you gave seems to be for time ordered. Any other comments after knowing these details?

Comment: OK cool! That does help me. In that case I think the most straightforward thing to do is to plug in the mode expansion terms of creation and annihilation operators in harmonic gauge -- schematically, $h_{\mu\nu}(x) \sim \int d^3 p (2p)^{-1/2} e^{i p \cdot x} a^\dagger_s(p) e^s_{\mu\nu} + a_s(p) e^s_{\mu\nu}$ -- then evaluate the VEVs of the products of creation operators (eg for a scalar $\langle a a^\dagger \rangle = 1$). Does that help?

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry for the delayed response. I am not yet accomplished with the calculations, though. I was wondering whether there is any other references you can think of which could help me with in between calculation steps. Thanks, again.